# To make navigation bar and tabbar transparent in swift

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uitabbarcontroller

I have a table view with a navigation controller and a tabbar controller. I want to make the navigation and tab bar transparent so that when I will scroll the tableview, it will not be hidden behind the tabbar and navbar.

my image url - 
[image]

In this picture, the top two images are on the navbar and button 3 images are on tabbar. How to make it, so that the table view will appear on the screen behind the tabbar and navbar in swift

Answer (score 0):

this should work with changing the alpha to 0.5 for example.

```
     navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 0.5)
```

Hope it works!